# Rails Sanatize SQL that uses a repeated value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails SQL Query that looks like:

```
    searchSQL = "SELECT a.id, a.asset_id, a.name, a.serial_number, a.category_id, a.status_id, a.user_id, a.location_id" +
            " from assets a where a.asset_ID LIKE '%"
            "%' OR a.name LIKE '%" + @searchBox + "%'" + 
            "OR a.serial_number LIKE '%"+@searchBox+"%'" +
            "UNION " + 
            "SELECT a.id, a.asset_id, a.name, a.serial_number, a.category_id, a.status_id, a.user_id, a.location_id" +
            " from assets a, users u where a.user_id = u.id AND (u.first_name LIKE '%" + @searchBox + 
            "%' OR u.last_name LIKE '%" + @searchBox + "%')" + 
            "order by asset_id ASC"
```

As you can see, it repeats the searchBox Value, I want to sanatize this using paramatized SQL, but I don't know how toadd the same value into every ? without repeating myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rails' string interpolation like this:

```
searh_term = "%#{@searchBox}%"
searchSQL = "SELECT a.id, a.asset_id, a.name, a.serial_number, a.category_id, a.status_id, a.user_id, a.location_id
               from assets a 
              where a.asset_ID LIKE '%%' OR a.name LIKE ?
                 OR a.serial_number LIKE ?
             UNION  
               SELECT a.id, a.asset_id, a.name, a.serial_number, a.category_id, a.status_id, a.user_id, a.location_id
                 from assets a, users u 
                where    a.user_id = u.id AND (u.first_name LIKE ?
                   OR u.last_name LIKE ?)
             order by asset_id ASC"

results = Model.find_by_sql(searchSQL, search_term, search_term, search_term, search_term)
```

You will have to pass a value for every ? in your query.
Note that you can avoid concatenating strings, ruby supports multiline string literals.